# How to get an array of tkinter custom GUI objects

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get an array of a custom tkinter object (it is a GUI window that shows a video stream).

I am running into errors with the code I tried to write.
I made a function to make the custom object and tried to make an array of those objects.

I am getting the following error:

> File "array_videoFeeds.py", line 60, in 
> app = FeedCams(root)      File "array_videoFeeds.py", line 8, in **init**
> self.initialize()   File "array_videoFeeds.py", line 54, in initialize
> self.b = self.videowindow()   File "array_videoFeeds.py", line 11, in videowindow
> self.videowindow = window NameError: name 'window' is not defined

Here is my python code:

```
import tkinter as Tk
import numpy as np

class FeedCams(Tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self,parent):
      Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.parent = parent
      self.initialize()

   def videowindow(self):
      self.videowindow = window
      self.cap = cap
      self.width = self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
      self.height = self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
      self.interval = 20 # Interval in ms to get the latest frame

      # Create canvas for image
      self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.window, width=self.width, height=self.height)
#      self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

      # Update image on canvas
      self.update_image()

      dynamic_windows.append(videowindow)

   def update_image(self):
      # Get the latest frame and convert image format
      self.image = cv2.cvtColor(self.cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # to RGB
      self.image = Image.fromarray(self.image) # to PIL format
      self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image) # to ImageTk format

      # Update image
      self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=self.image)

      # Repeat every 'interval' ms
      self.videowindow.after(self.interval, self.update_image)


   def initialize(self):
      '''
      Draw the GUI
      '''
      self.parent.title("RUN ON START TEST")       
      self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
      self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

      self.frame = Tk.Frame(self.parent)  
      self.frame.pack(fill=Tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)

      # Create a array of videos
      self.a = np.zeros((3,3))
      for i in range(0,self.a.shape[0]):
          for j in range(0,self.a.shape[1]):
               self.b = self.videowindow()
               self.b.grid(row=i,  column= j)

# Start the main program here               
if __name__ == "__main__": 
   root=Tk.Tk()
   app = FeedCams(root)   
   root.mainloop()
```

How can I successfully make this work?

**UPDATE:**
I changed the line of code based on one of the replies to ***self.a = np.zeros((3,3))***.

There error has been updated in the question.

Comment: Should `np.videos((3,3))` be `np.zeros((3,3))` instead?

Comment: I tried that and it gives the same error

Comment: I don't think you get the same error after changing `np.videos((3,3))` to `np.zeros((3,3))`.

Comment: @acw1668 you are correct. I have made that change based on your suggestion and I get a different error. Thanks for your input.